# Proving power rule without logarithms

Tags: real-analysis, limits

in most answers I have read in a few sites, the exponential definition and logarithms are used to define the general power function with real exponents.
Is there a way to prove the power rule without the definition of logarithm?
For a rational $q$, $(x^q)'=qx^{q-1}$ by using "composition of continuous function is continuous" and then applying the chain rule.
For a real exponent I go as follows. Let $x_0$ be in the interval $(0,\infty)$ and let $\alpha>1$ (for convenience), let $a_n$ be any sequence approaching $\alpha$ such that $a_n-\frac{1}{n}\leq \alpha \leq a_n+\frac{1}{n}$, then (again for convenience assume $x_0>1)$ we have the inequality
$$\frac{x^{a_n-\frac{1}{n}}-{x_0}^{\alpha}}{x-x_0} \leq \frac{x^{\alpha}-{x_0}^{\alpha}}{x-x_0} \leq \frac{x^{a_n+\frac{1}{n}}-{x_0}^{\alpha}}{x-x_0} $$
Now using the squeeze test and knowing that derivatives in the sides are known since they are rational exponents and also assuming that the middle is differentiable and is some real number:
$$\left(a_n-\frac{1}{n}\right )x_0^{a_n-\frac{1}{n}-1}\leq \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0;x\in (0,\infty)x\neq x_0} \frac{x^{\alpha}-{x_0}^{\alpha}}{x-x_0} \leq \left(a_n+\frac{1}{n}\right )x_0^{a_n+\frac{1}{n}-1}$$
Finally using the comparison principle again we get that the limit in the middle is $\alpha x_0^{\alpha-1}$.
Perhaps my question isn't clear enough but I want to know whether or not such derivative of the general power function is ultimately dependent on the exponential function and logarithm, or in short if such proof is valid without any mention of the logarithmic and exponential functions, thanks in advance.